# Declare static classes so that they can be stored within List

Tags: c#

I am developing a software that takes realtime-data and extracts a number of features from that depending on user input. Each available feature consists of one method that takes an array of doubles and return the wanted feature, such as this one for the MeanAbsoluteValue:

```
public static class MeanAbsoluteValue{
    public static double Calculate(double[] data){
        return data.Sum(s => Math.Abs(s)) / data.Length;
    }
}
```

Since each of the features only has the one Calculate method I was thinking of trying to rewrite them so that they can be collected and chosen from that Collection.

I have tried writing an Interface for them to use, but since they are static this was not allowed.

Is there a way of doing this? And if so, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You won't be able to leverage polymorphism using static classes.

Comment: Can't you use lambdas or delegates?

Comment: I am not sure what about a abstract class having static method , i know you can force them to implement , but if the implemented logic we can use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an array of delegates constructed from the `Calculate` methods of these classes, like this:

```
Func<double[],double>[] array = new Func<double[],double>[] {
    MeanAbsoluteValue.Calculate
,   MeanValue.Calculate
,   Deviation.Calculate
//  ...and so on
};
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/koimIG).

Answer (score 2):

Store delegates to your functions in a dictionary, and look them up by name

```
 var methods = new Dictionary<string, Func<double[], double>>();
 methods.Add("MeanAbsoluteValue", MeanAbsoluteValue.Calculate);

 ...
 public double DoFunc(string name, double [] args)
 {
    var func = methods[name];
    return func(args);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a collection of Func...

```
var list = new List<Func<double[], double>(MeanAbsoluteValue.Calculate, Average.Calculate)
var accum = 0;
foreach(var func in list)
{
    accum += func(new [] {1,3,4,});
}
```